# SwiftUI - Override the system font with multiple styles

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, swiftui

So SwiftUI gives us a nice `.font()` extension that lets us set the font size, style, weight, etc. of text. This mirrors CSS's font attributes nicely, and even comes with nice shorthands like `.font(.title)`, `.font(.body)`, `.font(.caption)`.

CSS shines when it comes to custom fonts, allowing us to import font faces from one or more files that collectively define several weights and styles within the same family. You can then use that font everywhere automatically by declaring a font family at the top level of the document, and then all font declarations will use that font automatically.

iOS allows us to import custom fonts, but it seems to fall short when it comes to *using* them. I'm looking for a way for iOS to mirror CSS's behavior.

I have 10 font files for a single font family: 5 different weights (light, regular, semi-bold, bold, and extra-bold) each with a regular and italic style. I am able to instantiate `UIFont`s for these fonts, but I'm looking for a way to set this font family globally so that I can declare `.font(.title, weight: .bold)` and have it implicitly use my font family's bold variant with the `title` size.

I am aware of ways to globally override the font, but I am specifically looking for a way to use multiple fonts from the same family to have automatic bold and italic capabilities. If there is a nice SwiftUI way to do this, that would be preferred, but a UIKit solution is fine as well.

EDIT: Another thing I should have mentioned is that I would like the default font of every `View` to use my font even with no `.font()` modifier. So if I have

```
Text("Hello, world")
```

it should use my font with the default weight and size (I think this is `.body`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can start be defining a custom `ViewModifier` to handle the logic of choosing the right type and size of a font:

```
struct MyFont: ViewModifier {
    
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
    
    public enum TextStyle {
        case title
        case body
        case price
    }
    
    var textStyle: TextStyle

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
       let scaledSize = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: size)
       return content.font(.custom(fontName, size: scaledSize))
    }
    
    private var fontName: String {
        switch textStyle {
        case .title:
            return "TitleFont-oBld"
        case .body:
            return "MyCustomFont-Regular"
        case .price:
            return "MyCustomFont-Mono"
        }
    }
    
    private var size: CGFloat {
        switch textStyle {
        case .title:
            return 26
        case .body:
            return 16
        case .price:
            return 14
        }
    }
    
}
```

Inside it you define an enum for all the text styles you would like to reuse across your app. You can use the same names as native `Font.TextStyle` such as `.title`, `.body` or define your own such as `.price` in the example above.

For each case of `TextStyle` you have to declare the name of the font and its default size.
If you include `sizeCategory` as in my example the font would adapt for dynamic type.

You can also define an extension on `View` to be able to apply this modifier in the same way as the native `font(_ font: Font?)`.

```
extension View {
    
    func myFont(_ textStyle: MyFont.TextStyle) -> some View {
        self.modifier(MyFont(textStyle: textStyle))
    }
}
```

Now you can apply it like this:

```
Text("Any text will do").myFont(.title)
Text("£3.99").myFont(.price)
```

For the default `Text` without a modifier applied you could either use Mahdi BM's solution or define your own type:

```
struct MyText: View {
    
    let text: String
    
    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text).myFont(.body)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yea, after digging into this a **lot** yesterday, I'm realizing that I'm not going to be able to just override all the system fonts for this. The solution you provided here is the cleanest.

Comment: I think I can combine your solution and @Mahdi's so that at least I can override the default font when there are no modifiers.

Answer (score 6):

You can override system's default environment font by using a `.environment()` modifier on top of a view. you can use it on top of your first view so it will be applied to all your views.

```
.environment(\.font, .custom("Your_Font_Name", size: theFontSizeYouPrefer))
```

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly when the font is not overridden for a particular view. However, every time I use the `.font()` modifier, it switches back to the system font. Is there a way for me to override the system font as well?

Comment: In my project i'm currently using an extension for that matter. you could probably do something like this: 
extension View {
    func customFont(size: CGFloat = defaultSizeHere) -> some View {
        self.font(.custom("Your_Font_Name", size: size))
    }
}

Comment: Yea, I'm aware that that is an option. I was looking for a way to hook in so that I can still use the built in styles (`.body`, `.title`, `.callout`) but have them use my font.

Comment: I don't think thats possible. The system can't customise your custom font. however, you can see the font sizings here, and using an enum and an extension, you'll be able to do the same thing with a little bit(or quite a bit?) of work. link: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/